# Three Stacks N cards

Tags: mathematics, combinatorics

You have n cards that have been numbered from 1 to n. You will divide these cards into three stacks such that, the sum of the numbers of any pair of cards taken from any stack will not be a perfect square. Under this condition what is the maximum value that n can take?

If n=9, three stacks can be divided as (1,2), (3,4,7,8), (5,6,9) and the sum of any pair will not be a perfect square.

Comment: If we construct a graph with the integers from 1 to n as vertices and an edge between any two numbers that sum to a square, this question is asking for the highest n such that the resulting graph is [tripartite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multipartite_graph). Testing whether a graph is tripartite is NP-complete; there is no simple check for it.

Comment: @user2357112 If this is the case, then wouldn't the two vertices that share an edge still be in the same set?  You want the opposite - i.e. no such edge exists between elements of any set.

Comment: @Trenin: You might have misread the definition of a k-partite graph. All edges have to go from one part to a different part; edges between members of the same part are forbidden.

Comment: Is there a nice way to get to the answer instead of a brute force approach like that used by @czarlarry though?

Comment: This would be a nice problem on math.SE, wanna ask it there too?

Answer (score 7):

I found that the range

> n = 3 to 85 inclusive
> was possible, but
> n = 86
> was not

Solution:

> Made a graph with each edge connecting vertices whose sum is a perfect square. I then three colored the graph using a backtracking sort of algorithm. Basically an implementation of the situation user2357112 described.

---

Code (Python):

```
from __future__ import division
from math import sqrt

def genGraph(l):
    ret = []
    for k in range(0, l+1):
        ret.append([0,[]])
    top = int(sqrt(l+l-1))
    for k in range(2, top+1):
        for k2 in range(1, k*k//2+1):
                if(k*k-k2 != k2 and k2 < len(ret) and k*k-k2 < len(ret)):
                        ret[k2][1].append(k*k-k2)
                        ret[k*k-k2][1].append(k2)
    return ret

def color2(g):
    g[1][0] = 1
    return color2H(g, 1)


def color2H(g, n):
    if(n >= len(g)):
        return g
    vc = [1,2,3]
    for k in g[n][1]:
        if(k < n and g[k][0] in vc):
                vc.remove(g[k][0])
    if(len(vc)==0):
        return
    for k in vc:
        g[n][0] = k
        if(color2H(g, n+1)):
                return g
    g[n][0] = 0
    return

def makeExampleStacks(coloredGraph):
    stacks = [[] for s in range(3)]
    for v in range(1, l + 1):
        stacks[coloredGraph[v][0] - 1].append(v)
    for i in range(1,3):
        if len(stacks[i]) == 0:
            stacks[i].append(stacks[0].pop())
    return stacks
```

Use cases:

> 1. Show a possible distribution for $85$:
>
> ```
> >>> for stack in makeExampleStacks(color2(genGraph(85))):
> ...     print(stack)
> ...
> [1, 2, 4, 9, 10, 13, 17, 20, 22, 25, 28, 30, 33, 37, 38, 41, 46, 49, 50, 57, 58, 65, 66, 69, 73, 74, 76, 81, 82, 85]
> [3, 7, 8, 11, 15, 16, 19, 23, 24, 27, 31, 35, 36, 39, 43, 44, 47, 51, 52, 55, 59, 60, 63, 67, 68, 71, 72, 75, 79, 80, 83]
> [5, 6, 12, 14, 18, 21, 26, 29, 32, 34, 40, 42, 45, 48, 53, 54, 56, 61, 62, 64, 70, 77, 78, 84]
> >>>
> ```
>
> 2. Show $86$ is impossible:
>
> ```
> >>> if color2(genGraph(86)):
> ...     print("possible")
> ... else:
> ...     print("impossible")
> ...
> impossible
> >>>
> ```

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling.SE. I've formatted your code, please check whether the same gives any error message or not (i'm currently using mobile so won't be of much help).

Comment: Just added return ret to genGraph

Comment: Made it compatible with Python3 while still working in Python2. Also Added a function to return the example stacks that the graph represents (while making sure all stacks contain at least one card) and provided usage.

Comment: I don't know if this is linked but 84+85=169=13*13 so we reach a new perfect square at this moment

Comment: I also tried to figure out why the graph stops being tripartite at 86. Basically, what's added to the graph at this stage is the node 86 with its 4 edges (connecting it to 14, 35, 58 and 83). 86 cannot get any of the three colours, as the four neighbours have to have three different colours. (This can be seen from the '85' graph.) In particular, either (14, 35 and 58) or (14, 58 and 83) have to have three different colours. I couldn't find a simple explanation as to why this is. (I'm not sure there is one - dropping a small number of random nodes from the '85' graph changes this behaviour.)

Answer (score 5):

An upper bound is

> $n = 3361$

Note that

> If there are $6$ pairs summing to square numbers such that there are only $4$ numbers used across the pairs then we cannot split these $6$ pairs into $3$ stacks in any way.

Now we can

> search for such scenarios by first forming all sets of $3$ pairs that contain $3$ distinct numbers (for example $\{(6, 19), (6, 30), (19, 30)\}$) and then checking for a distinct $4^\text{th}$ number less than the maximum of those that forms a pair with each of the $3$.

Some code:

```
def squarePairs(n):
    for a in range(1, n + 1):
        for b in range(a + 1, n + 1):
            if ((a + b) ** .5) % 1 == 0:
                yield a, b

def squarePairTriples(n):
    sPs = list(squarePairs(n))
    for ai, a in enumerate(sPs):
        for bi, b in enumerate(sPs[ai + 1:]):
            if a[0] == b[0]:
                c = (a[1], b[1])
            elif a[0] == b[1]:
                c = (a[1], b[0])
            elif a[1] == b[0]:
                c = (a[0], b[1])
            elif a[1] == b[1]:
                c = (a[0], b[0])
            else:
                continue
            if c in sPs[bi + 1:]:
                yield a, b, c

def findD(squarePairTriple):
    tripleVs = set()
    for t in squarePairTriple:
        for v in t:
            tripleVs.add(v)
    for d in range(1, max(tripleVs)):
        if d not in tripleVs:
            for v in tripleVs:
                if ((d + v) ** .5) % 1:
                    break
            else:
                return d
```

Now we can find an upper bound like so:

```
>>> g = squarePairTriples(5000)
>>> for t in g:
...     d = findD(t)
...     if d:
...             t, d
```

The first case that this produces is:

> ```
> (((2, 359), (2, 3362), (359, 3362)), 482)
> ```
>
> and:
>  $2+359=19^2$;
>  $2+3362=58^2$;
>  $359+3362=61^2$;
>  $2+482=22^2$;
>  $359+482=29^2$; and
>  $3362+482=62^2$

---

Edit: This (original route) is not quite right...

For a brute force approach that does not explode as fast as a naive approach we can note that

> at the maximal $n+1$ (the first impossible point) there will be $4$ pairs summing to square numbers such that there are only $4$ numbers used across the pairs and $1$ of these will be in all $4$ pairs (thus we cannot split these $4$ pairs into $3$ stacks).

Edit: not right because:

> There will never be such a set of four pairs - as one number would have to be in one of the pairs twice.

Furthermore

> if we have the square pairs for $n-1$ we can find the square pairs for $n$ by just inspecting the new pairs that may be formed and appending them to the ones for $n-1$.

We may

> be able to improve upon this when we are checking for the condition by only inspecting new combinations of $4$ square pairs formed.
>  but i have not done that yet.

Code so far:

```
from itertools import combinations

# note: this will return non-square pairs if n gets big, due to the floating point arithmetic
def squarePairs(n, prevKnown=[], prev=0):
    res = list(prevKnown)
    newCards = [i for i in range(prev + 1, n + 1)]
    for a in newCards:
        for b in range(1, a):
            if ((a + b) ** .5) % 1 == 0:
                res.append((b, a))
    return res

def findImpossible():
    n = 3
    sPs = squarePairs(n)
    fSPsSet = set()
    while 1:
        for fSPs in combinations(sPs, 4):
            fSPsSet.clear()
            for fSP in fSPs:
                for i in fSP:
                    fSPsSet.add(i)
            if len(fSPsSet) == 4 and any(sum(1 for fSP in fSPs if i in fSP) == 4 for i in fSPsSet):
                return n, fSPs
        print("{0} is possible".format(n))
        sPs = squarePairs(n + 1, sPs, n)
        n += 1
```

`findImpossible` is currently running and has shown that

> $3$ to $75$ inclusive are possible.

Comment: Your attempted simplification doesn't work. If we build a graph whose vertices are integers from 1 to n, where an edge exists between any two integers that sum to a square, you're testing for the presence of a 4-clique in the graph, but we really need to test if the graph is [tripartite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multipartite_graph), or 3-colorable. This problem is [NP-complete even for planar graphs](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1008294); the constraints propagate in complex ways that make it harder than just looking for a 4-clique.

Comment: I don't really understand why the problem given is isomorphic to the problem you give. If we do find such a four-clique we've found an n that wont work, right?

Comment: Yes, but even without such a 4-clique, it might be impossible to find a valid 3-coloring. For example, take a look at the pentagon with a point in the middle in [this image](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/images/eps-gif/ChromaticNumber_875.gif), and imagine if the vertices of the graph were integers and the edges represented two numbers adding up to a square.

Comment: @user2357112 OK so I will find an upper bound then :)

Comment: I love these comments. Reading them - for me - feels like puzzle in itself.

Comment: @BmyGuest So I figured it out - we want to put the cards into 3 stacks (A, B, C) such that no pair of cards in a stack sums to a square, so each possible square-sum-pair can be considered an edge in a graph and there are three ways to distribute such a pair across the stacks ((A,B),(A,C),or (B,C)) which can be considered our colours. If a fourth colour is required we'd need another stack.

Answer (score 3):

#### Partial Answer

> I have computed the number of possibilities for each n (the number of ways we can make the 3 stacks). It confims that n=85 is the maximum, the highest number of possibilities is 7619346 for n=41. I don't know what to do with it but it might help someone to solve it :
>
>   [image: Number of possibilities to make 3 stacks]
>
> ```
> n     number_of_possibilities
> 2     3
> 3     4
> 4     9
> 5     18
> 6     36
> 7     72
> 8     144
> 9     288
> 10    576
> 11    1152
> 12    2304
> 13    3072
> 14    4096
> 15    5120
> 16    10240
> 17    20480
> 18    40960
> 19    55296
> 20    74304
> 21    98384
> 22    132068
> 23    182936
> 24    233720
> 25    323152
> 26    445464
> 27    623276
> 28    782192
> 29    954344
> 30    954344
> 31    1258056
> 32    1703706
> 33    1489096
> 34    1320119
> 35    1145964
> 36    1646108
> 37    2315230
> 38    3323978
> 39    4754466
> 40    6953224
> 41    7619346
> 42    6288985
> 43    5070996
> 44    3322568
> 45    2505684
> 46    2035007
> 47    1408492
> 48    964234
> 49    1104016
> 50    1388292
> 51    1122328
> 52    951420
> 53    820878
> 54    758979
> 55    812308
> 56    848847
> 57    784393
> 58    713755
> 59    695534
> 60    502734
> 61    305033
> 62    125214
> 63    76664
> 64    70928
> 65    55729
> 66    33338
> 67    22795
> 68    18242
> 69    8638
> 70    5525
> 71    4902
> 72    5488
> 73    3226
> 74    3144
> 75    1811
> 76    849
> 77    576
> 78    443
> 79    483
> 80    513
> 81    622
> 82    742
> 83    912
> 84    563
> 85    187
> 86    0
> ```

Answer (score 2):

**Partial Answer:  Lower Bound**

I have found a solution for

> $n=60$

With the following sets

> $\{45, 49, 43, 58, 7, 20, 1, 11, 56, 22, 39, 30, 26, 50, 13, 33, 47, 37, 41, 46, 52, 60, 28 \}$, $\{55, 5, 29, 3, 57, 23, 34, 38, 32, 36, 19, 27, 53, 42, 25, 12, 14, 40, 10, 18, 21, 8, 16, 51 \}$, $\{9, 24, 31, 4, 15, 6, 35, 54, 59, 2, 17, 44, 48 \}$

Although, this is also just a lower bound.

P.S. Please feel free to check my sets.

Comment: This seems to work for n=85 : [[1, 4, 6, 13, 14, 17, 18, 20, 25, 26, 28, 33, 34, 37, 40, 42, 49, 52, 54, 57, 62, 65, 70, 73, 76, 78, 85], [2, 5, 9, 10, 21, 22, 24, 29, 30, 32, 38, 41, 45, 46, 48, 50, 53, 56, 58, 61, 64, 66, 69, 74, 77, 81, 82, 84], [3, 7, 8, 11, 12, 15, 16, 19, 23, 27, 31, 35, 36, 39, 43, 44, 47, 51, 55, 59, 60, 63, 67, 68, 71, 72, 75, 79, 80, 83]]

Comment: @Lord of Dark. Yeah that looks good. Have you managed to get higher than this?

Comment: no I take random samples at each steps but it always stops at 85 or before

Comment: Well I've done more test and it keeps ending at 85. If only I had enough power or an optimised script to check it... but now I'm pretty sure 85 is the upper bound, or at least something very special happens there !

Answer (score 1):

#### Partial Answer

The minimum for n is

> 34

We could make the following division :

> {1-2-4-6-9-11-13-17-18-20-22-26-28-33}
>  {3-5-7-8-10-12-14-16-19-21-23-25-27-32-34}
>  {15-24-29-30-31}

Comment: I'm curious on how you found this.

Comment: All this shows is a way to do it for the given n, right? So by "The minimum for n is" you mean "a lower bound minus 1 for n is" assuming it is possible all n lower than that, yes?

Comment: @Marius You get that if you start at 1 and put each number in the first possible set without making a square sum.

Comment: but this does not guarantee there is no other solution for a bigger number. It just proves you can take this approach up to a specific number.

Comment: Yes it's just a partial answer that proves that "the maximum value that n can take" is bigger than 34

Comment: Easily by completing group 1 and 2 as much as possible (3 and 8 can't go with 1,6 can't go with 3)and then by making the third group (with 15 that could not go with 1 nor 10).
It is therefore a minimal value and absolutly not an optimal one.

Comment: @Laurent Maybe you should state that in your answer so people won't be discouraged to search for an alternative.

Comment: I can definitely say that it works for the next number also. If you move 14 in the last group you can put "your number +1' in the second group. So yours is not the max possible value. (didn't want to write the actual number so I won't spoil it)

Comment: I build a python script, I had to stop at 37 because there were more than 2 millions possibilities to make the 3 stacks.

Answer (score -1):

Partial strategy.

Let's say that N is the first number for which this is impossible.

> This means we have to find 4 different number up to N for which any combination of 2 add up to a perfect square.
>  Let's make these numbers $x_1 < x_2 < x_3 < x_4$
>  Among these numbers, the last one is actually the number N.

This means:

> $x_1 + x_2 = k_1^2$
>  $x_3 + x_4 = k_2^2$
>  $x_1 + x_3 = k_3^2$
>  $x_2 + x_4 = k_4^2$
>  $x_1 + x_4 = k_5^2$
>  $x_2 + x_3 = k_6^2$
>  where all $k_i$ are integers.

From the equations above and the imposed order of the numbers we get that:

> $k_1^2 \neq k_3^2$
>  $k_1^2 \neq k_5^2$
>  $k_3^2 \neq k_5^2$

Also, adding the equations 2 by 2  we get :

> $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 = k_1^2 + k_2^2 = k_3^2 + k_4^2 = k_5^2 + k_6^2$

From the last 2 things proved above we get that

> the sum $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4$ can be written as a sum of 2 squares in at least 3 different ways.

I got stuck here a bit and called my good friend Google and he gave me this:

> http://www.rowan.edu/colleges/csm/departments/math/facultystaff/osler/110%20SUM%20OF%20TWO%20SQUARES%20IN%20MORE%20THAN%20ONE%20WAY%20MACE%20Small%20changes%20Oct%2008%20%20Submission.pdf
>  In the pdf linked, there is a list of numbers that can be written as 3 different sums of squares.
>  Example: $325 = 1^2+18^2 = 6^2+17^2 = 10^2+15^2$
>  in this case 1, 18, 6, 16, 10, 15 are the $k$ numbers we are looking for.
>  Based on the order of the numbers we imposed, we get that $x_1+x_2$ has the smallest value among the numbers listed above, and $x_3+x_4$ is the largest.
>  G0ing further we can establish this:  $k_1 < k_3 < k_4<k_2$.
>  And we cannot fit in this chain, $k_5$ and $k_6$.
>  So in the example above we would have:
>  $x_1 + x_2 = 1$
>  $x_3 + x_4 = 18^2$
>  $x_1 + x_3 = 6^2$
>  $x_2 + x_4 = 17^2$
>  $x_1 + x_4 = 10^2 or 15^2$
>  $x_2 + x_3 = 15^2 or 10^2$
>  or
>  $x_1 + x_2 = 1$
>  $x_3 + x_4 = 18^2$
>  $x_1 + x_3 = 10^2$
>  $x_2 + x_4 = 15^2$
>  $x_1 + x_4 = 6^2 or 17^2$
>  $x_2 + x_3 = 17^2 or 6^2$
>
>   Obviously this won't work because $x_1 + x_2 > 2$ but this was just an explanation.
>
>  I also tried for the next number 425 but got nowhere.
>  And I kind of lost my patience at 5125.

I will pick this up later again, but in case someone wants to continue, feel free to write an answer based on mine and I will gladly upvote it.

Comment: This doesn't work. For example, consider a hypothetical where $a+b$, $b+c$, $c+d$, $d+e$, and $e+a$ are all squares, and adding $x$ to any of $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$, or $e$ also produces a square. These numbers have to be split into at least 4 sets, but there is no set of four of them for which every pair sums to a square.

Comment: I am not sure I follow. Why is there an e? I am looking for 4 numbers

Comment: You're looking for 4 numbers, but looking for 4 numbers isn't enough. The example I gave is a situation where a 4-number check wouldn't be sufficient. It's based on a standard example of a graph with chromatic number 4 and no 4-cliques.

Comment: It might help to look at the [pentagon with a point in the center in this image](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/images/eps-gif/ChromaticNumber_875.gif). $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$, and $e$ are the vertices of the pentagon, and $x$ is the point in the center.

Comment: It starts to get clear. It might not be enough to find 4 numbers but it is mandatory.

Comment: The upper bound found by JonathanAllan fits my logic. Why the downvote? Please explain.

Answer (score -2):

Well i personally believe that:

> This procedure can be done for all n. Correct me if im wrong please.

Something we will need later:

> T1: Two perfect squares differ by atleast 3.  Proof: x >=1: (x+1)^2-x^2= 2x+1 >= 3

Ok the base my proof is:

> I will use induction on n. The induction base can be n=9 as in the question. In the induction step we know that the hypothesis is true for n=k-1 now we need to prove the hypothesis for n =k.

Ok now the proof begins:

> Now we construct our 3 sets for n=k-1. Now we name the sets :A,B,C. Now if the numbers 2 and 1 are in A and we add k to A, and S(A) becomes a square according to T1 if we take 2 or 1 S(A) will be not a squre and if we add for exmaple 2 to another set and it doesnt become a square then its ok otherwise we dont pick 2 and we pick 1. In the case which only one of 1, 2 are in A(say x is that number), if when adding k to A,  the sum becomes a square we can take x and put it in the set where the other of 1,2 is if that set becomes a square we can just add the other number back to A. Now if both of 1,2 are in the same set other than A, if when adding k to A its sum becomes a square we can give 1 to A if the other set becomes a square too we can switch 1 and 2. Now the last case: if 1,2 are in separate sets other than A,  we can do the above procedures for another set like B because this case ia covered. This solution (all of it) depends on T1.

I hope my answer is atleast partially true.

Comment: Omg im sooo srry, why doesbt spoiler tag work...

Comment: Ok seems i fixed it... Srry again...

Comment: If by "S(A)" you mean the sum of the elements in A, then you should re-read the question. It doesn't say that the sum of the subsets is not a perfect square. It says that the sum of any pair of elements from within a set is not a perfect square.

Comment: @Duncan: sorry my bad...